# The quadratic form of the inverse of a self-adjoint operator is bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H=(H, (\cdot, \cdot))$ be a Hilbert space and $T: D(T) \subset H \to H$ a self-adjoint operator. Suppose that there is $c>0$ such that
$$
(T(u), u) \geq c \|u\|^2,\; \forall \; u \in D(T)\setminus \{0\}, \tag{1}
$$
where $\|u\|:= \sqrt{(u, u)}$, for all $u \in H$. As a consequence of $(1)$ we see that ${\rm Ker}(T)=\{0\}$ that is $T$ is one-to-one. Also, suppose that the range ${\rm R}(T) \subset H$ of $T$ is closed. Then, since $\{0\}^{\perp}={\rm Ker}(T)^{\perp}={\rm R}(T)$ we have ${\rm R}(T) = H$. In other words, $T$ is surjective. Thus, there exists the inverse $T^{-1}$ of $T$.

**Question.** There exists $c_1>0$ such that
$$
(T^{-1}(u), u) \leq c_1 \|u\|^2,\; \forall \; u \in H? \tag{2}
$$
Moreover, $c_1= \frac{1}{c}$?

I think that $c_1>0$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $T$. That's true? Or can I explain in terms of $T$ the constant $c>0$?  How can I use this to prove $(2)$?

References are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can assume that $c$ is the greatest possible constant satisfying the inequality, i e.
$$c=\inf_{\|u\|=1,\ u\in D(T)}\langle Tu,u\rangle.$$
By the Schwarz inequality we get $\|Tu\|\ge c\|u\|.$ For $v\in \mathcal{H}$ we have $v=Tu$ for a unique $u\in D(T).$ Thus $$\|T^{-1}v\|=\|u\|\le c^{-1}\|Tu\|=c^{-1}\|v\|.$$ Hence $T^{-1}$ is a bounded operator and $\|T^{-1}\|\le c^{-1}.$ Moreover $$\langle T^{-1}v,v\rangle =\langle u, Tu\rangle\ge 0,$$ i.e. $T^{-1}$ is a positive operator.

Finally, again by the Schwarz inequality, we obtain $$\langle T^{-1}v,v\rangle \le \|T^{-1}v\|\,\|v\|\le c^{-1}\|v\|^2.$$

Concerning the constant $c,$ it is a smallest point in $\sigma(T).$ We also  have $\|T^{-1}\|=c^{-1}.$ The number $c$ does not need to be the eigenevalue of $T.$ Let $d\mu(x)=x^{-2}\,dx $ for $x\ge 1.$ Consider the operator $T$ acting on $L^2([1,\infty),\mu)$ by $$Tf =xf, \qquad D(T)=\{f\in L^2(\mu)\,:\, xf\in L^2(\mu)\}.$$
Then $T^*=T$ and $$\langle Tf, f\rangle \ge \|f\|^2_{L^2(\mu)},$$ but the number $c=1$ is not an eigenvalue.

**Remark** There is no need to assume that $R(T)$ is closed. It follows from the selfadjointness and  inequality $(1).$ Indeed, the graph of $T$ is closed. Assume $Tu_n\to v.$  Then
$$\|Tu_n-Tu_m\|\ge c \|u_n-u_m\|.$$ Hence $u_n$ is convergent as is it is a Cauchy sequence. Let $u_n\to u.$ As $Tu_n\to v$ and the graph of $T$ is closed, we obtain $u\in D(T)$ and $Tu=v,$ i.e.$\ $$v\in R(T).$

Comment: How did you get $\|T^{-1}\|=c^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @Victor Hugo The number $c^{-1}$ should be equal the upper bound of $\langle T^{-1}v,v\rangle $ for $\|v\|=1.$ It can be proved by means of the square root $T^{1/2}.$ As $c$ is a smallest point in $\sigma(T)$ then $c^{-1}$ is the largest point in $\sigma(T^{-1}).$

Comment: Do you know any references for this result?

Comment: @Victor Hugo I do not know any particular reference. Definition of $c$ implies that $T−cI $ is nonnegative but does not admit a bounded inverse. Hence $c$ belongs to $σ(T).$ Therefore $ c^{-1}$  belongs to $σ(T^{−1}).$ Thus the norm of $T^{-1}$ is at least $c^{-1}.$ The opposite inequality is contained in your answer as well as in mine.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question note that

$$(Tu,u) \geq c \|u\|^2 \hbox{ for all } u \in D(T) \setminus \{0\}$$
implies that
$$\|u\|\|Tu\| \geq (Tu,u) \geq c \|u\|^2 \Rightarrow \|u\| \leq \frac{1}{c}\|Tu\|.$$

Therefore,

$$(T^{-1}u,u)\leq \|T^{-1}u\|\|u\|\leq \frac{1}{c}\|T(T^{-1}u)\|\|u\|=\frac{1}{c}\|u\|^2.$$

For the other questions I have to think more.